# FormArray of nested FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, angular15

When data is downloaded from the network, I have to dynamically create and push `FormGroup` elements into a `FormArray`. But the child component doesn't really exist yet as it'd be created based on the array element existing.

So I've got something like this:

```js
class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
   formArray = new FormArray([])
   formGroup = new FormGroup({
       children: this.formArray
   })

   ngOnInit() { 
      this.service.get(...).subscribe(x => this.rebuildChildren(x))
   }

   rebuildChildren(items: Item[]) {
       this.formArray.clear()
       items.forEach(x => {
           const group = new FormGroup({
               child1: ChildOneComponent.createFormGroup(x),
               child2: ...
           }) 
           this.formArray.push(group)
       })
   }
}

class ChildOneComponent {
   protected readonly formGroup: FormGroup

   static createFormGroup(item: Item) {
      return new FormGroup({...})
   }
}
```

I want the child components to handle the creation of the `FormGroup` structure so everything is cleanly segmented. If this *weren't* a `FormArray` type thing I'd just attach to the parent via a `viewProviders` injection of `FormGroupDirective`.  However, since the children are dynamically created based on the `FormArray`, I'm not sure how to handle the `FormGroup` creation.

In the above example, I'll get a fully populated `FormArray`, but then when Angular creates `ChildOneComponent`'s inside of a loop, the `formGroup` for that specific component doesn't actually exist.

A better example of what I'm doing can be seen on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwyy35)

Comment: Can you give more details about that mapping? Am I correct: for every item are you creating a formgroup, with how many children, dynamic number?

Comment: @ZsoltB I added a StackBlitz to the description. But yes, for every item I'd add a new formgroup to the array. The number of items is dynamic and simply depends on how many results come back from the API call.

Comment: Sorry, I forget about this. Somethin is not clear for me: for every item you are creating a fromgroup of other groups(how many subgroups there?), after that you push those into a form array, based on that form array do you want to render what exactly?

Comment: So the form is a space, and a space contains multiple subspaces, so the FormArray represents each subspace.  Each subspace has 10 or so properties related to the infrastructure, and then 10 or so related to allocation.  So instead of one huge component for subspace I made infrastructure and allocation  components themselves, with a `FormGroup` representing their data.

Comment: My issue really boils down to the fact that those child components, that define the form groups, aren't created by angular until I generate the `FormArray` elements. But the array wants the `FormGroup` to be pushed, which the child defines.  So it's like a chicken and egg.

Comment: Can you add a sample of a template how do you want to use that form array?